# Why can't close my eth0 by command `ifconfig eth0 down`?

Tags: ifconfig, wordpress

Let us start from closing my eth0.192.168.1.4 is binded with eth0.

```
root@hwy:/home/debian8# ifconfig eth0 down   

root@hwy:/home/debian8# route -nv    

Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 wlan0
192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 wlan0
192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth0

root@hwy:/home/debian8# ifconfig

eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr e0:3f:49:57:4b:d1
inet addr:192.168.1.4 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::e23f:49ff:fe57:4bd1/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:918 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:195407 (190.8 KiB) TX bytes:29304 (28.6 KiB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:728348 (711.2 KiB) TX bytes:728348 (711.2 KiB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:21:5d:26:c1:10
inet addr:192.168.1.101 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::221:5dff:fe26:c110/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:6556 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:5709 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:3528018 (3.3 MiB) TX bytes:999397 (975.9 KiB)
```

Maybe the eth0 is closed .

```
traceroute -i eth0  stackoverflow.com
traceroute to stackoverflow.com (104.16.36.249), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Something confued me that 192.168.1.4 can still be used in my local network.
There is a wordpress build on my local network.

```
root@hwy:/home/debian8# cat /etc/hosts
192.168.1.4 mywp.com
```

And all my url in the wordpress is in the form of http://mywp.com/wp/?p=2026.
If eth0 is closed by the command `ifconfig eth0 down`,the ip `192.168.1.4`
can't be used,but why my wordpress can be visited on my local network?
There is only one result that the eth0 still work ,why can not be closed by the command
`ifconfig eth0 down` ?

Think to  Warren Young .

```
ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
root@hwy:/home/debian8# ping 192.168.1.4
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1001 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
```

Maybe this is a important clue:
My wordpress was build on local pc,there are two ips and two net cards on my local pc,192.168.1.4 was binded with eth0 ,192.168.1.101 was binded with wlan0.eth0 was banned by command  `ifdown eth0`.

Comment: Are you sure the other computers on the local network are using the 192.168.1.4? Is the 192.168.1.4 mywp.com record in their /etc/hosts?

Comment: You cannot have the same netblock in eth0 and wlan0

Comment: only two computers ,yes there is 192.168.1.4 mywp.com record in it's /etc/hosts,but the other computer ip is 192.168.1.100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ifconfig eth0 down`

Unless you're doing something uncommon (e.g. applying IP aliases) you should not be using `ifconfig` (or its successor, [`ip(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip)) directly. You should say `ifdown eth0` here. That takes care of many things that `ifconfig` does not.

> `traceroute -i eth0  stackoverflow.com`

Your route table says the default route is via `wlan0`, not `eth0`, so you're not testing what you think you are.

> 192.168.1.4 can still be used in my local network

Of course. If you look back at the `ifconfig` output, you will see `UP` in the `eth0` section.

> `192.168.1.4 mywp.com`

You should not be using `.com` or other official TLDs for private networks. For purely local hosts defined in `/etc/hosts`, you don't need to fully-qualify them at all. This is perfectly legal:

```
192.168.1.4 mywp
```

With that `/etc/hosts` entry, you can visit `http://mywp` in your browser. Be careful: this movement in modern browsers to unify the search and location boxes means that typing `mywp` alone in the box will likely be treated as a web search term, not a host name. Most browsers will skip that if you include some sort of punctuation, so that `mywp/` will tell the browser you mean for it to treat `mywp` as a host name, not a web search term.

If you feel the need for fully-qualified domain names, adjust your networking configuration to assign a local domain name to the LAN, such as `literature.private`. The `.private` TLD is a traditional option for local-only domains. (Another common alternative is `.local`.) The `literature` part I just took from your user name.

Having done that, the same `/etc/hosts` entry will still be looked up correctly if you go to `http://mywp.literature.private` in your web browser.

Comment: ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Reboot your box and try again. I suspect your previous manual `ifconfig` commands have confused the `ifdown` program.

Comment: i am still puzzled!!why 192.168.1.4 can be accessed?

Comment: ifdown eth0
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Are you certain your system actually *has* an `eth0`? I know it shows up in the list above, but that could just be because of prior misconfiguration. For example, maybe your system is using [Consistent Network Device Naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming), so your Ethernet interface is called something other than `eth0`. Or, maybe your system is wifi-only, so there is only `wlan0`.

Comment: I am sure that eth0 exists first, wireless card was installed one month age,now two net card in my home pc.